# How to determine the cause of not achieving a target in using machine learning model

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Please I want to know if it is possible to know the specific variables' influence in testing a sample data to a model. The model below clarifies the question;

Given a dataset to predict the score of students.

```
ID  Studies hours   Games hours lectures hours  social Activities   Score
0   1   20  5   15  2   78
1   2   15  6   13  3   69
2   3   31  2   16  1   95
3   4   22  2   15  2   80
4   5   19  7   15  4   71
5   6   10  8   10  8   52
6   7   13  7   11  6   59
7   8   34  1   16  1   96
8   9   25  6   15  1   83
9   10  22  3   16  2   76
10  11  17  7   15  1   66
11  12  28  2   14  2   87
12  13  21  3   16  3   77
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedKFold
from numpy import absolute
from xgboost import XGBModel
import pickle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from xgboost import plot_importance 

data = pd.read_csv("student_score.csv")

def perfomance(data):
    X = data.iloc[:,:-1]
    y = data.iloc[:,-1:]
    model = XGBModel(booster='gbtree')
    #model = XGBModel(booster='gblinear')
    model.fit(X, y)
    cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=3, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
    # evaluate model
    scores = cross_val_score(model, X,y, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
    # force scores to be positive
    scores = np.absolute(scores)
    metrics = ('Mean MAE: %.3f (%.3f)' % (scores.mean(), scores.std()) )
    # save the model to disk
    filename = 'score.sav'
    pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)
    # load the model from disk
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open('score.sav', 'rb'))
    result = loaded_model.predict(X_test)
    print(result)
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,15)
    plot_importance(model)
    plt.show()
```

Feature Importances :

```
[5.6058721e-04 6.7560148e-01 3.1960118e-01 4.2312010e-03 5.4962843e-06]
```

The feature importance is the general importance ranked by the model.

What I need now is:

when I pick A sample test say `test = pd.DataFrame([{"Studies hours":15, "Games hours":6, "lectures hours":13,"social Activities":3}])`
and predict; `loaded_model.predict(test)` and I get a score like 68, Which of the variables specifically (not the general importance) didn't make this specific sample test not score 100 but rather 68?
For Example, the model should tell me studies hours were bad or were less than expected.

Can Machine Learning Model do that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: Explainable AI is a **huge** topic in itself, and it cannot be answered as a *programming* question of "how to do it" as you ask here; for an overview, see https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/12870/which-explainable-artificial-intelligence-techniques-are-there/24138#24138

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The topic you're describing is called model explainability or interpretability. The more sophisticated the model, the more accurate it is, but the harder it is to explain (really generally speaking). SHAP values are the most common way I see folks explaining the effect of each feature on predictions generally, and each feature value on the prediction for a given observation. The most common visualization of SHAP values is the force plot. It looks like this:

[image]

The blog from which I took this image explains how to build a force plot for any model: [Explain Any Models with the SHAP Values — Use the KernelExplainer](https://towardsdatascience.com/explain-any-models-with-the-shap-values-use-the-kernelexplainer-79de9464897a)

Comment: Thank you very much @Thorspear. But not fully answered. With the force_plot,   5.11 is the predicted value. Total sulfur dioxide + Alcohol + Sulphate + ... = 5.11 ; So I want to be able to get the value of each of the independent variables.

Comment: The size of the bar size is the SHAP value, which is the value for each independent variable. If you want the individual numbers rather than a plot, you can access those as well (see the “individual force plot” section of the blog above)

Comment: More specifically, the SHAP value tells you how each of the values for each independent variable moved the final prediction for the observation up or down from the average. So In the above example, having a sulphates value of 0.52 decreased the prediction by a little more than  0.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at explaining the model's decision for a specific example using [SHAP](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). A [waterfall](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/api_examples/plots/waterfall.html) or [force](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/shap.plots.force.html) plot can show why the model scored 68 for a specific example based on the the input variables.